# angular material layout-fill IE11 issue

Tags: angularjs, layout, internet-explorer-11, flexbox, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material for a webApp, and having an issue with layout-fill attribute.
the code:

```
  <body>
      <md-toolbar layout="row">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools" style="background-color:red">
          <span>LOGO</span>
          <span style="text-align:right;color:black" flex><h1>APP NAME</h1></span>
        </div>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-content layout="row" flex layout-fill  style="background-color:blue;">
        <div id="pagina" layout="row" flex layout-fill style="background-color:green;" layout-align="center center">
          <div>Hello</div>
        </div>
      </md-content>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

It's suppossed to show "hello" word in the middle of the screen, and it's working ok in Chrome and Microsoft Edge, but not in IE11. Is there any additional config needed for IE11?

Comment: After more tests I realised that I need to tell the body (parent) that its children are being flexed - display: flex. I've added layout="column" to the body and now it works on Chrome, Edge and IE11.